# How to apply cloth modifier/physics only on selected faces?

Tags: mesh, physics, cloth-simulation

I completed my low-poly character modeling today (in **one-piece**). So my question is, how to apply cloth modifier/physics on selected faces (Given in the picture)? I need extra hanging cloth should animate like a cloth!

[image: Photo not loaded :)]

I actually tried adding cloth physics when these faces are selected, but it applied to the whole mesh which is turning my model into a cloth :(

Comment: Cloth physics are always applied on a per-object basis, you can't apply it to part f a mesh only as far as I know. You could try creeating a *Vertex Group* including all other vertex and use it for pinning, but not sure how well it would workout.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yes, making "Vertex Group" worked! Although I wanted the collars of coat as cloth but with different cloth properties, like high "Spring" value which is not possible :(